# how send an array value from ajax to php without using url

Tags: php, ajax

basically i am doing searching. and this searching takes on on blur event of input field.there is all d result of searching are retrieve through XML in from a php page,there is a pop up window where i have received value through URL but due to large size of array in URL we can not access this system to any other system.so please tell me how i can send the value without using URL from Ajax to a php pop window,,,
right now i m using this function to send value from Ajax to php by url,,,give me proper solution anyone. for without using url.

Comment: It would be great if you could share the code you've got so far

Comment: Are you asking how you can send data to the server without putting them in the URL ? If so, maybe you want to know how to make POST ajax request.

Comment: According to what you wrote, you want to access php file without knowing it's filename. Doesn't seem like a very possible thing :/

Comment: @Andrius : "send the value without using URL" : I think he meant "not putting the value in the URL". I hope so at least.

Comment: the main problem i see is the large size. So use a POST method. simple.

Comment: Yeah, hope so, dystory :) I am still quite new to this site, so I got a question: does this confusing question deserve a downvote or no? :)

Answer (score 1):

Either You can call

```
$.post({...});
```

or better

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    ...
});
```

This way the data is sent through POST method of HTTP and is not present in the URL.